# Jquery Cookieplugin Set Path

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a simple a question about setting the path to a cookie. I want the cookie to be accessible from any directory. Currently the code I have does not allow me to access it except in the directory I set the cookie in.

I read that I need to use something like this when setting the cookie:

```
  $.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/' });
```

But I am unsure of where I need to input into my script seen below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#saveForm").click(function() {
$.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), { expires: 365 });
 });
$("#Website").val($.cookie('myCookie'));
});

</script>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `path` as part of options

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveForm").click(function () {
        $.cookie('myCookie', $("#Website").val(), {
            expires: 365,
            path: '/'
        });
    });
    $("#Website").val($.cookie('myCookie'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping... It looks like this works if I have the submit field on the same page. But it does not work on a page I have a paypal submit field with a different ID. Is there something I need to do adjust so I can retrieve the cookie on different forms with different IDs?